# get cluster labels in mllib kmeans pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

How do I get cluster labels when I use Spark's mllib in pyspark? In sklearn, this can be done easily by

```
kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=k,random_state=1)
temp=kmeans.fit(data)
cluster_labels=temp.labels_
```

In mllib, I run kmeans as :

```
temp = KMeans.train(data, k, maxIterations=10, runs=10, initializationMode="random")
```

This returns a `KmeansModel` object. This class doesn't have any equivalent of sklearn's `labels_`

I am unable to figure to out how to get the labels in mllib's kmeans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use predict on the training data:

```
temp.predict(data)
```

or

```
parsedData.map(temp.predict)
```

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question. However, that was then, and this is now, and now in pyspark 2.2 KMeans has no train method and the model has no predict method. 
The correct way to get the labels is

```
kmeans = KMeans().setK(k).setSeed(1)
model = kmeans.fit(data)
prediction = model.transform(data).select('prediction').collect()
labels = [p.prediction for p in prediction ]
```

Comment: You are referring to the newest Spark ML (dataframe-based API), while the question was about the older MLlib, still available as the RDD-based API.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It's just that I was looking myself for a way to get the labels, only found this post, which wasn't helpful because I am using the dataframe-based API, figured it out and decided to share with the world. And I didn't want to create another question that would be branded as "duplicate", so I put it here.